# Elasticsearch for subquery

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I have written an ES query which first matches the movie name and
return the content ID (1-1-1000017)
then I have written another query to pull data related to the above ID

Can we merge both and write a single Elasticsearch query?

sample query :

```
GET /movies/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "_source": "contentId",
  "query": {
  "match_phrase_prefix": {
     "contentData.M.title.S": "dabang"
   }
   } 
 }


GET /movies/_search?size=1000
{
 "query": {
  "term": {
     "contentId.S.keyword": "1-1-1000017"
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: can u please share your index mapping, sample index data, and expected search result?